# Getting NSMetadataItem for local files on iOS App Sandbox

Tags: metadata, sandbox, nsfilemanager, foundation, nsmetadataquery

I am aware that on iOS you can only use `NSMetadataQuery` for iCloud files. However, according to Apple's [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/SearchScope.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001841-CH2-SW3), you can still get `NSMetadataItem` by searching for the file you want manually with `FileWrapper`:

> iOS allows metadata searches within iCloud to find files corresponding files. It provides only the Objective-C interface to file metadata query, `NSMetadataQuery` and `NSMetadataItem`, as well as only supporting the search scope that searches iCloud.
>
> Unlike the desktop, the iOS application’s sandbox is not searchable using the metadata classes. In order to search your application’s sandbox, you will need to traverse the files within the sandbox file system recursively using the `NSFileManager` class. Once matching file or files is found, you can access that file in the manner that you require. You are also able to use the `NSMedatataItem` class to retrieve metadata for that particular file.

However, I couldn't find a way to get the `NSMetadataItem` from a local file on iOS sandbox. You can initialize `NSMetadataItem` from a file URL but that's available only on macOS. `FileManager` also doesn't seem to have an API to retrieve `NSMetadataItem` from it.

How do I get `NSMetadataItem` for local files on iOS App Sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSMetadataQuery` to query iCloud files, add observer to get notification.

```swift
metaDataQuery.searchScopes = [NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope, NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDataScope]

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.metadataQueryDidFinishGathering),
name: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGathering, object: metaDataQuery)
metaDataQuery.start()
```

```swift
func metadataQueryDidFinishGathering(notification: NSNotification) {
    let result: [NSMedatataItem] = (notification.object as! NSMetadataQuery).results as! [NSMedatataItem]
    // handle result
}
```